# Log errors after running robocopy command

Tags: powershell, copy, migration, command, robocopy

I am running a robocopy command to copy files from one folder to another like below -

"Robocopy source destination filename"

Some files are not getting copied although they are present at source. How to log those files in a log file?

Answer (score 0):

`robocopy /?` is the help for the utility

One of the options is `/LOG`, wherein you can log the output to a file.

`/V` is verbose which will show skipped files.

If some files are not being copied, they must not be matching either source path, or filename fileglob.  Validate path and fileglob with `Get-ChildItem`.

Answer (score -1):

You can consider to store the source file list in a variable first
Then validate by using foreach loop and if/else to verify are the files already copied, if not then write the message into error.log

Comment: robocopy works on folders and validates on copy.  Your suggestion is to use copy and write your own loop and validation.